# Core 2 duo t6600 graphic driver update on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, cpu, intel-core2

I am having so problems updating the drivers on my friends old laptop that has a core 2 duo t6600 which he updated to windows 10 and no longer has any drivers for windows 10 so i tried installing the latest version but it said that the computer did not meet the requirements. Sorry if this is a simple question I don't normally work on older computers.

Comment: Your CPU does not have a GPU built in. To properly answer the question, additional information is required.

Comment: @DanielB - I should have known not to submit my comment without looking up the CPU in question first.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, that model is not officially supported by windows 10, but that does not mean it is not compatible. Theres is a trick available that can get the driver installed.

Get the [64-bit](http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2013/04/200000265_b70e6e89dc0f24433f6fcc6b33d5f160f30a33cd.cab) version or the [32-bit](http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2013/04/200000268_69e51a687acc555a97b220bb0facacfc2060c7dc.cab) cab packed driver from windows update dig-site.

- Extract the Drivers using WinRAR/7Z
- Go to Device Manger
- Go to Display Adapters and expand it.
- Right Click on that and finally hit on Update Driver Software
- Install Driver Software Manually
- Browse for the driver software
- Go to the location of previously extracted drivers folder
- Click Next for successfully installation of Drivers.

Note: if you receive the error "*The best driver software for your device is already installed*" you will have to do some additional steps:

- Uninstall the drivers by right click --> uninstall
- After that Windows 10 will black Screen
- Do a forced power off by holding the power button until power-off
- Power back on and go to Device Manger
- From Device Manager find the Display Adapters and expand it.
- You will see Microsoft basic video drivers. Updated those according to the initial steps.

Answer (score 0):

Graphic driver depends on chipset or internal external graphic card u are using for that u can download CPUZ tool to find which motherboard or graphic chip or graphic cards is being used and then google find driver of that chip or card from the manufacture company website download and install

As sometime some companies stop providing drivers for newer windows  then u can find the graphic chipset driver from alternative company which may work if the graphics chipset not modified or changed

if it does not work  then find some driver softwares like driver easy professional  or driver pack solution DRP which automatically detects drivers and install alternative drivers link provided

[Driver pack solution](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://drp.su/&ved=2ahUKEwjE1ozQwf3nAhVIzTgGHTW1BxoQFjAAegQIBxAD&usg=AOvVaw1BB7p_tsTAyIUNJzQYrUVk)

> if any of the answer solution work let me know if not then provide me details of graphic chipset or card  i will find for you and if solution works then don't forget to vote or accept answers